# Extracting multiple values from a hash in ruby, modifying the original hash and returning the extracted values

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a YAML file which I am using to seed some Ruby on Rails models. I load this using `YAML.load(filename)`. Some of the keys need some post processing before creating the RoR models, for example, files need to be opened from filenames.

I want to extract two values from the hash into variables, leaving the hash without these values present.

What is the most idiomatic way of doing this in Ruby?

Edit:

I have tried doing:

```
value1 = hash.delete(:key1)
value2 = hash.delete(:key2)
```

which gives me `value1` and `value2` fine but leaves hash unchanged.

Comment: How `hash` is created ? what is its class (use `puts hash.class`) ?

Comment: hash is created by YAML.load(...)['some key']. I will print the class when I get back to my code in 10 mins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about to use an enumerator and extract each value from hash, retaining the hash in it's original entity.

```
hash = { :key1 => value1, :key2 => value2 }

# Iterates over values
hash.each_value {|val| print val}
```

or another alternative:

```
print hash.shift[1] while not hash.empty?
```

Normally the `delete` method delete the specified key from hash and returns the deleted value.

```
hash.delete (:key1) # => returns the deleted value. Now the hash should contain {:key2=>value2}
```

Answer (score 0):

The hash generated by `YAML.load` uses string keys rather than symbol keys. I was trying to delete using symbol keys so nothing was being deleted.